# How can I parse a JSON object in PHP? How can I retrieve the values of some specific fields of this JSON object?

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

I am absolutely new in PHP and moreover in Laravel framework (I don't know if Laravel provides some utility class for this kind of tasks). I came from Java.

So I have the following problem:

Into a class I perform a call to a REST web service, something like this:

```
    $response = $client->get('http://localhost:8080/Extranet/login',
        [
            'auth' => [
                'dummy@gmail.com',
                'pswd'
            ]
        ]);

    $dettagliLogin = json_decode($response->getBody());

   \Log::info('response: '.(json_encode($dettagliLogin)));
```

`$response->getBody()` contains the returned JSON object, this is the output of the previous `\Log::info()`:

```
{
    "id":5,
    "userName":"Dummy User",
    "email":"dummy@gmail.com",
    "enabled":true
}
```

So I have the following problems:

1) What exactly returns the `json_decode()` function? I really can't understand because PHP is not strongly typed and I have not a declared return type.

This is the method signature:

```
function json_decode($json, $assoc = false, $depth = 512, $options = 0)
```

and in the related doc it says `@return mixed`. What exactly means "mixed"?

2) Anyway the main problem is: I have to use the content of the previous returned JSON object and put these value into the related field of an array like this:

```
$attributes = array(
    'id' => HERE THE id FIELD VALUE OF MY JSON OBJECT,
    'username' => HERE THE email FIELD VALUE OF MY JSON OBJECT',
    'name' => HERE THE userName FIELD VALUE OF MY JSON OBJECT,
    );
```

So I think that I have to parse the value of the `$response->getBody()` or of the `json_decode($response->getBody())` to obtain these values. But how exactly can I do it? What is the neater way to do it? Does the Laravel framework provide some utility to do it?

Comment: There is no such thing like a "JSON object" (even if Java pretends there is). [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is the text representation of some data structure. It can be used to re-create the data structure used to generate it.

Comment: The fastest way to understand how it is looks like, just 

$dettagliLogin = json_decode($response->getBody());
`dd($dettagliLogin);`

This will output the JSON decoded variable, so you can see what is this. It can be an object, array, number, depends on the response.

Comment: has my answer helped you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For better understanding, let's first describe - what's JSON?
**It's a way of representing objects (arrays, objects, etc) in a string.**

> 1) What exactly returns the json_decode() function? I really can't
>   understand because PHP is not strongly typed and I have not a declared
>   return type. This is the method signature:
>
> function json_decode($json, $assoc = false, $depth = 512, $options =
>   0) and in the related doc it says @return mixed. What exatly means
>   mixed?

json_deocde converts the JSON string into the original "structure" it represent.

@return mixed means that the returned value of json_decode can be any type of variable. If the JSON represent an array - it would be an array type, if it represent an object - it would be an object type.

> 2) Anyway the main problem is: I have to use the content of the
>   previous returned JSON object and put these value into the related
>   field of an array like this:
>
> $attributes = array(
>       'id' => HERE THE id FIELD VALUE OF MY JSON OBJECT,
>       'username' => HERE THE email FIELD VALUE OF MY JSON OBJECT',
>       'name' => HERE THE userName FIELD VALUE OF MY JSON OBJECT,
>       );

In order to make sure which type of variable your JSON represent, you can use `var_dump(json_decode($json));`. Anyway, it's a class object.

Therefore:

```
$object = json_decode($json);

$attributes = array(
    'id' => $object->id,
    'username' => $object->email,
    'name' => $object->userName,
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you `json` string is an object (not an array) it will return an object (of type `stdClass`). Mixed means it can be multiple things, so if it was a json array, you'd get an array.

Best thing to do is use `json_decode`, and then `var_dump` (or `var_export`) to see what you actually get.